# Generate elements with jQuery and Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am not sure how to do that. I have a model `Post` which I am showing when somebody hits `/posts/1`. Now this post belongs to someone. Which means I have another model called `User`. But there is more. Now a post can have a `Comment`. All of this works fine so far, because I am just loading everything as soon as somebody hits `/posts/1`. Now I would like to show all posts from the user when somebody hits `/users/1`. I created a view called `posts/_post.html.erb` and in the view of the user I have this code snippet: `<%= render @posts %>`. This works so far! But now I would like to show comments of every post **BUT** only if he hits a button called *Show comments*. Now this should trigger an ajax call and then show my comments.

My question here is, should I create a `GET-Route` where I get all of the comments from the post as **JSON** and then create the HTML-Elements with Javascript or is there a better version with Rails, because I already have a view called `comments/_comments.html.erb`? Do I really have to defined the template once in the view file and once in the Javascript?

Comment: I usually do it like this: ajax call, in the reply i `render` the templates

Comment: @Fallenhero As I understood, you create a GET-Route, a method in a controller (e.g. `getComments`) and a view where all the comments are rendered and than you just append the result (which is already in HTML) to an html selector?

Comment: yes, exactly like that.